# OpenVPN Connect issue

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I am having trouble connecting to my VPN and I think I may have located the issue but I am unsure how to solve it. I can connect fine through my mobile device but when I try to connect through my MacBook it just immediately fails and says `Cannot connect to VPN Server` I ran the command `sudo tcpdump -i en1 port 1194` while attempting to connect and noticed something odd. Below is the results when I try to connect, there are only two packets:

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on en1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
23:42:43.566777 IP 192.168.1.10.49566 > c-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.hsd1.il.comcast.net.openvpn: Flags [S], seq 2466172422, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 3,nop,nop,TS val 130819740 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
23:42:43.588234 IP c-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.hsd1.il.comcast.net.openvpn > 192.168.1.10.49566: Flags [R.], seq 0:32, ack 2466172423, win 0, length 32
```

Notice that on the end of the `PTR/FQDN` it has `.openvpn` appended to it. I am unsure of the proper name of it, but it is the string that I blocked out the public IP address of the server with "X's".

I am guessing this is the issue because if you try and us `curl` to browse to that it fails but removing the `.openvpn` it successfully resolves. I am wondering if anyone knows how I can get rid of the `.openvpn` at the end? I get my configuration file by browsing to `https://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:943` and downloading the script that is automatically configured. It has always worked in the past but for some reason it is not working anymore. If anyone has any ideas I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.openvpn` you are seeing is not part of the "FQDN" as you call it. Rather, that is indicating which port number the packet is being sourced from. Notice the first packet in that capture is sourced from `192.168.1.10.49566`, meaning IP address `192.168.1.10`, port `49566`. In the case of the openvpn port (port 1149), tcpdump is resolving that to a "friendly" named port for you, based off of the standard port assignments that can be found in `/etc/services`.

So, the issue you're having has nothing to do with this. You'll need to do some more troubleshooting to find the source of the problem.

Comment: The error log says unable to obtain session ID. However I listen for any requests on the server to that port and no packets are ever received. I am guessing the issue lies in the configuration of my MacBook since I am able to connect fine from the mobile app.

Comment: Yes, that would be the first place I'd look.

Comment: I got it to work. The problem was that I only had the UDP 1194 port forwarded and not the TCP also. I only Forwarded the UDP because that was under the recommended Port to be forwarded in the documentation, unless I missed it somewhere. Anyways, it was because of you mentioning the `/etc/services` I decided to look in there for OpenVPN and I noticed that both 1194 TCP/UDP were listed. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason to use TCP, don't do it. Performance will suffer. Use UDP instead. You likely just need to modify your client confit to use UDP.